# change url to another url with hashtag to use it in jquery

Tags: jquery, url, redirect

I use jquery tabs .. when the visitor go to : mysite.com/#user-20 I use jquery to load the user data in a hidden div .. I get data from my php file :  mysite.com/user/20

the problem is : if the user go directly to mysite.com/user/20  he will get unorganized data because there is not header of footer for that template file named (user.tpl)

I want to redirect the visitor if he print in the url ( mysite.com/user/20 ) , redirect him to ( mysite.com/#user-20) 
like twitter .. if you go to http://twitter.com/twitter  he will redirect you to http://twitter.com/#!/twitter

I want the same !
I use codegniter framework :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood it properly, but in javascript (not strictly jQuery) you can redirect the user to another page with this:

```
location.href = 'http://mysite.com/#user-20';
```

Comment: thank you pistacchio .. I used it bu I was need to another line to do my goal :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to get current window url and then manipulate this url with your requirement(regex will be more helpfull in that case).

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
```

then assign newly formed url to window in this way-

```
window.location.pathName = newlyFormedURL;(for ex-'http://mysite.com/#user-20')
```

Comment: I do not want to use jquery .. however it's ok now . I found a solution form your answers gays ..
I will submit the answer bellow .. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to do this in codeIgniter, but the ideal approach for the same would be to have your javascript load data in AJAX, i.e. the request mime type for the same would be application/json. Hence in your controller for the url /user/20 you should then check the request mime type and respond accordingly. If the mime type is application/json then great, otherwise you may redirect the user to the appropriate url you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody, I really appreciate your answers :)
I did it with this code :

```
 var current_url = location.href ;
 if( current_url.indexOf( 'user/' ) !== -1 ) { // if not using # hashtag , so redirect him
 var user_id = current_url.substring(current_url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 location.href = 'http://mysite.com/#user-'+user_id ;
}
```